# React passing value from dropdown back to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My parent component looks like:

```
<div>
    <Dropdown items={companiesData} handler={handleClick} />
    ....//More stuff
   </div>
```

companiesData is an array of items with id, companyName etc.

I am creating my dropdown this way:

```
const Dropwdown = ({ items, handler }) => {
  return (
    <select onChange={handler}>
      {items.map(({ id, value, companyName, companyType }) => (
        <option
          key={id}
          value={value}
        >
          {`${companyName}, ${companyType} `}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  )

}
```

I know that from the `handleClick` function I can access `e.target.value` and get the value of the dropdown, but what if I want to get the whole object of that selected value (e.g. containing id, value, companyName etc.)and pass it back to the parent component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Dropdown, add value property to select and use the id like value={this.state.selectedValue}.

So you will have that value in ev.target.value.

Then, in your parent, you can do something like: `companiesData.filter(company => company.id === ev.target.value)`. And you have the info there.
and of course set the selectedValue (using hooks or normal setState)

Answer (score 0):

Another option (if you don't want to do filtering) is to simply send `e.target` to your handler instead of `e.target.value`.

In your handler, retrieve the info you need like this:

```js
const parentHandler = target => {
    const targetOptions = target.options;
    const selectedValue = target.value;
    console.log("selected value", selectedValue);
    console.log("all html options array", targetOptions);
    console.log("selected option html", targetOptions[target.selectedIndex]);
    console.log(
      "selected option name",
      targetOptions[target.selectedIndex].getAttribute("name")
    );
  };
```

see a [demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-option-pass-extra-value-fix-wpbck?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: how do I retrieve the company.id this way though

Comment: you need to add an additional attribute to your option ... i have updated the codesandbox demo..